# Email not being fowarded to google mail (gmail)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have set up a fowarding filter in Outlook that fowards emails to Gmail. However, i am not receiving any emails in gmail. I also tried running filter on only one email, and still i am not seing it in gmail.

If I send email manually, then i get email.

I checked spam folder. I have seen a lot of questions about this, but I havent found useful answer.

Comment: How do you set up the fowarding filter ? By rules? Can you see the sent messages in the account you fowards emails? Do you configure you gmail account on Outlook client?

Comment: I filter them by keyword. Yes, i can see sent emails. No, i dont have gmail acc configured in outlook, is this important?